# How to run julia-lang file - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, julia

**Want:**

> How do I run Julia files from my Mac terminal?

Julia on Mac is an app.

On terminal when I type `$julia` it is not a valid command.

How do I get to autocomplete julia as a legit command?

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Perhaps OP is a time traveler.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - How do I run a julia file "xx.jl" from Mac Terminal.

Comment: @JulesRies - I am sorry I could not get your point.

Comment: @suryakrupa I was joking. :) I've never seen a post on SO that was an answer instead of a question, so I was speculating that you were answering a question someone is going to ask in the future.

Comment: This question should be closed or cleaned up. The question part should be the question only. If the OP wants to answer his or her own question, that is absolutely fine, but the answer part needs to be an answer and not part of the question.

Answer (score 6):

**Answer:**

1. Install [Julia](http://julialang.org/downloads/)
2. `echo "alias julia='/Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'" >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. Close and re-Open Terminal
4. then just type

> $ julia

Voilá! Julia from Mac Terminal!

Answer (score 2):

Link the julia exectable into one of the directoties in your PATH. For example:

```
ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.3.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/bin
```

You could also use homebrew to install julia http://brew.sh, since the julia hb julia formula appears to do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Julia](http://julialang.org/downloads/) on Mac OSX,

I suggest to compile Julia from source and make install.